# Retrieving Parse.com objects with PHP script

Tags: php, parse-platform

I am creating a web application in which I need to retrieve objects from my Parse.com database in PHP. I can successfully retrieve the objects in JavaScript as shown below:

```
<script>
  var LandingSite = Parse.Object.extend("hospital");
  var query = new Parse.Query(LandingSite);
  query.find({
  success: function(results) {
    alert("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " sites.");
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
      var object = results[i];
      alert(object.id + ' - ' + object.get('name'));
    }
  },
  error: function(error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
  });
  </script>
```

However, I need the code to be in PHP and the PHP script does nothing(shows no sign of it being executed). I will post the entire file just incase it is something other than just the PHP script:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <script src="//www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>LSDirectory</title>

        <style>

         body{
            background-color: burlywood;
         }

         img{
            width: 100px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            background-color: white;
         }

        </style>

        <script language = "javascript">
        Parse.initialize("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"); //hidden keys
         function siteChanged( i ) {
            var siteName = document.getElementById( "landingSite" ).options[ i ].innerHTML;
            //alert( i );

            document.getElementById( "locationNumber" ).value = i;
            document.getElementById( "resetPageForm" ).submit();
         }

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <h1>Landing Site Directory Data Control</h1>

 <?php
 $query = new ParseQuery("hospital");
  $results = $query->find();
  echo "Successfully retrieved " . count($results) . " sites.");
// Do something with the returned ParseObject values
for ($i = 0; $i < count($results); $i++) { 
  $object = $results[$i];
  echo $object->getObjectId() . ' - ' . $object->get('name'));
}
  # Get the recursive location number.
  $locationNumber = $_REQUEST['locationNumber'];
  if( empty( $locationNumber ) ) {
    $locationNumber = 0;
  }

  # Open the database. 
  # Pull out the locations and put in an array.
  $aLandingSites = array();

  # Fix the location of the images
  $base = 'http://www.gcap.eu/omosanya/images/';

  # This next section is hard-coded data but which would have been pulled from the database.
  $numberOfLandingSites = 5;

  $aLandingSites[1] = 'Basildon Hospital';
  $aLandingSites[2] = 'Addenbrookes Hospital';
  $aLandingSites[3] = 'Broomfield Hospital';
  $aLandingSites[4] = 'Norwich and Norfolk Hospital';
  $aLandingSites[5] = 'Royal London Hospital';

  $aBriefDescriptions[1] = 'Main landing site';
  $aBriefDescriptions[2] = 'New pad';
  $aBriefDescriptions[3] = 'Main landing site';
  $aBriefDescriptions[4] = 'Main landing site';
  $aBriefDescriptions[5] = 'Elevated helipad';

  $aElevations[1] = "101";
  $aElevations[2] = "53";
  $aElevations[3] = "88";
  $aElevations[4] = "14";
  $aElevations[5] = "310";

  $aImage1[1] = $base . "basildon1.jpg";
  $aImage2[1] = $base . "basildon2.jpg";
  $aImage3[1] = $base . "basildon3.jpg";
  $aImage4[1] = $base . "basildon4.jpg";

  $aImage1[2] = $base . "addenbrookes1.jpg";
  $aImage2[2] = $base . "addenbrookes2.jpg";
  $aImage3[2] = $base . "addenbrookes3.jpg";
  $aImage4[2] = $base . "addenbrookes4.jpg";

  $aImage1[3] = $base . "broomfield1.jpg";
  $aImage2[3] = $base . "broomfield2.jpg";
  $aImage3[3] = $base . "broomfield3.jpg";
  $aImage4[3] = $base . "broomfield4.jpg";

  $aImage1[4] = $base . "norfolk1.jpg";
  $aImage2[4] = $base . "norfolk2.jpg";
  $aImage3[4] = $base . "norfolk3.jpg";
  $aImage4[4] = $base . "norfolk4.jpg";

  $aImage1[5] = $base . "royallondon1.jpg";
  $aImage2[5] = $base . "royallondon2.jpg";
  $aImage3[5] = $base . "royallondon3.jpg";
  $aImage4[5] = $base . "royallondon4.jpg";

 ?>

 <select name="landingSite" id="landingSite" onchange="siteChanged( this.selectedIndex );">
  <option value="0">-- select --</option>

 <?php
  for( $i = 1; $i <= $numberOfLandingSites; $i++ ) {
    if( $i == $locationNumber ) {
        $j = 'selected';
    }
    else {
        $j = '';
    }

   echo "<option value=\"$i\" $j>$aLandingSites[$i]</option>";
  }
 ?>

 </select>

    <div>

     <form action="savedata.php">
     <h2>Data</h2>
     <table border="0">
      <tr>
       <td>Brief description</td><td><input type="text" name="briefDescription" value="<?php echo $aBriefDescriptions[ $locationNumber ] ?>" /></td>
      </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Elevation</td><td><input type="text" name="elevation" value="<?php echo $aElevations[ $locationNumber ] ?>" size="3" /> ft</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Etc</td><td><input type="text" name="" /></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" value="save" />
  </form>

     <h2>Images</h2>
     <table border="0">
   <tr>
    <td>
     <img name="image1" src="<?php echo $aImage1[ $locationNumber ] ?>" />
     <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="saveimage.php">
      <input type="file" name="newImage1" accept="image/jpeg" />
     </form>
    </td>
    <td>
     <img name="image2" src="<?php echo $aImage2[ $locationNumber ] ?>" />
     <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="saveimage.php">
      <input type="file" name="newImage1" accept="image/jpeg" />
     </form>
    </td>
    <td>
     <img name="image3" src="<?php echo $aImage3[ $locationNumber ] ?>" />
     <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="saveimage.php">
      <input type="file" name="newImage1" accept="image/jpeg" />
     </form>
    </td>
    <td>
     <img name="image4" src="<?php echo $aImage4[ $locationNumber ] ?>" />
     <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="saveimage.php">
      <input type="file" name="newImage1" accept="image/jpeg" />
     </form>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>


    </div>

    <! hidden form>
    <form id="resetPageForm" action="http://www.gcap.eu/omosanya/lsdirectory.php">
     <input type="hidden" name="locationNumber" id="locationNumber" />
    </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

I am new to PHP so I really do not know what is wrong. Even when I simply write

```
<?php 
echo "Hello world!"; 
?>
```

The code is not executed. Please help!

Comment: If you say that a simple "hello world" is not executed, did you make sure to have PHP installed on your machine / server? You could set up xampp under windows:https://www.apachefriends.org/de/index.html

Comment: All of the other PHP code works though, like $aLandingSites = array();
$numberOfLandingSites = 5;$aLandingSites[1] = 'Basildon Hospital';

Comment: If your creating everything from scratch, you should skip Parse altogether. PHP's sql databases are far more robust in features. It also give you customization over your own site. Additionally, it gives you a great learning tool for php and practice as well. You can at anytime include parse to send push notifications, but if your using it just to store data, I would forego that and commit to sql databases.